# selecting the last 2 rows of a matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to select the last 2 rows in a matrix field:
You would expect that this could be easily achieved by using the following code.

```
{matrix}
    {if row_count >=  total_rows - 1}
        test
    {/if}
{/matrix}
```

However, this throws a syntax error:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   **expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code**
>   on line **168**

Using just "total_rows" works perfectly fine, adding the the "-1" causes the error.
( EE v 2.5.5 )

Comment: no math in templates or in conditionals. maybe with a math / calculate plugin.

Comment: any idea which plugin I could use for this ?

Comment: ehm, maybe MX calculator or search on devot-ee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TAking what Bhashkar Yadav suggested, you might now need to go with two matrix calls to achieve what yoku need.

```
{matrix orderby="row_id" sort="desc" limit="1" offset="1"}

{matrix_column}

{/matrix}
```

and

```
{matrix orderby="row_id" sort="desc" limit="1"}

{matrix_column}

{/matrix}
```

This should call the second last row first and then the last row. It's a little clunky, but I don't believe there is a better way to achieve what you need.

Comment: that should work, but there has to be an easier way. Are there any plugins that allow simple calculations in  conditionals ?

Comment: searching Devot:ee pulls up a list of math plugins which may help. http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=math&addon_version_support=ee2 I havne't used any of these myself, but hopefully one of them will do what you need.

Comment: You can use {previous_row} or {next_row} to get the second row.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [MX Calculator](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-calculator) and give something like this a go:

```
{matrix}
    {if row_count >= "{exp:mx_calc expression='{total_rows}-1'}"}    
        test
    {/if}
{/matrix}
```

What does that return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{matrix orderby="row_id" sort="desc" limit="2"}

{matrix_column}

{/matrix}
```

Comment: I need them do be in the right ( asc ) order..

Comment: Could you use {next_row}stuff{/next_row} BEFORE you output the content from the first row?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this... Haven't tried this so don't know for sure it will work.

Basically, flip the matrix so you reverse the order then get the first 2 items.

```
{matrix_field sort="desc" limit="2"}
    stuff
{/matrix_field}
```

*EDIT I see someone already suggested doing this, maybe combine with what I suggest below?*

Or maybe you could make use the {next_row} and {previous_row} matrix tags

```
{matrix_field offset="{total_rows}"}
    {previous_row}Stuff here{/previous_row}
{/matrix_field}
```

Like I said, haven't tested this so it may well not work but hopefully it will give you some ideas.